# AWS EC2 Instance Networks go up

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2

We have an e-commerce . in two instances EC2, made in rails using Redis and ElastichSearch
Lately we've been having issues with the Networks Metrics
Because the go up extremely fast, being inconsistent whit the analytics data regarding people browsing the page.
This triggers the cpu utilization to more than 90%, causing a collapse on our servers, making the page slow which cause our server to response HTTP STATUS 5XX.
The request count of our target groups in the load balancers are normal

Any idea how start to debug this issue, we don't have any change in months

These are the metrics

[Networks Average](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVVbk.png)
[CPU Utilizatiion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z4A9.png)

Comment: _inconsistent whit the analytics data_ then you might have inconsistencies with analytical vs *actual* traffic. Lots of traffic and high CPU is a good indication of a DOS attack; someone may be trying to upload large amounts of data in hopes of crashing your server. Brose the actual web server access logs and compare them to analytical logs during the time of the event. Also, kind of off topic for here.

Comment: Reviewing your graphs, both the large plateau from 1/9 to 1/11 looks like an extended attack, then another attack from 1/13 to 1/14. Natural ecommerce traffic does not show patterns like that over short periods of time, my assumption is that most of that traffic is bots.

Comment: How can i block these bots? we are new to aws. 
or some way to track the ip of the requests to block them

Comment: Check out [Fail2Ban](https://www.fail2ban.org) as one option, there are many. There may even be optional plugins for the ecommerce engine you are using.

Comment: What I mean by the inconsistencies in analytics, is that even with the maximum traffic in an event of 100 people at the same time we do not reach that consumption of networks and now at the moment of maximum value of the graph we have 40 people